# F# compiler documentation and F# data flow analysis library

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, data-analysis

I have two questions:

1. I was wondering if someone is aware of F# Compiler documentation or related resources (except for the compiler source code itself, I am currently looking it) - Information about the structure of the AST and the additional functions (if any) for parsing and traversing the tree will be helpful.
2. I also need F# library for data flow analysis, if any of you have any idea if such exists, please let me know.

Thanks :)

Comment: The only resources I have found are examples of VS extensions that use the compiler:

Answer (score 3):

This is not the best resource, but if you just want to parse and get the AST, see

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/source-code-for-f-depth-colorizer-extension/

and

https://github.com/brianmcn/FSharpDepthColorizer/blob/master/ParseTreeDepth/MyFSParser/MyParsing.fs

(look for 'ParseOneInputFile') as an example of a 'sample app that needs the parser'.

(I don't have anything to offer regarding the dataflow analysis.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I have already looked at this extension and it is quite useful. Another useful resource is F# refactor (http://fsharprefactor.codeplex.com/) it shows how to use the ParseOneInputFile as well as how to convert the given AST to custom AST representation.